# Android Studio WebView Youtube Video BlackScreen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to play a video in the WebView but somehow I get an blackscreen on the video but I can hear the sound of it. Would be really glad if someone can help me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView displayYoutubeVideo;
TextView button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe 
    width=\"560\" height=\"315\" 
    src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/WtO3_tF8niU\" frameborder=\"0\" 
    allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

    displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 
           (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0");

    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be missing `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the permissions of your activity in the manifest file. Since you are playing a flash video this should work out to make the WebView flash enabled. This is something that I encountered and the resolution was to add this permission.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you.It seems you missed some properties for the web view.

https://inducesmile.com/android/embed-and-play-youtube-video-in-android-webview/

Answer (score 0):

You must activate  Hardware acceleration if your android:targetSdkVersion is lower than 11 and have to set webChromeclient to your webview

```
displayYoutubeVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and in your manifest file add below line

```
 <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```